# Can I use NR in an expression within an interval expression in AWK?

Tags: awk

Ok I hope this is not a stupid question but I did search frustrating hard for an answer already if that helps,... I have the following `awk` expression that I'm working on:

```
awk '{str="";a=0;while (a++<15) str=str "0,";{ sub(/^.{6}/,"&" "1,",str) }; print str}' sample.txt
```

*Sample.txt* can be any text file, at this point it doesn't matter as it just drives the repetitions (it's a means to an end hopefully). The output looks something like this (depending of course on how many lines are in your Sample.txt file):

```
0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
```

What I really want to do however is something like this:

```
awk '{str="";a=0;while (a++<15) str=str "0,";{ sub(/^.{2*NR-1}/,"&" "1,",str) }; print str}' sample.txt
```

Which should generate output like this:

```
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
```

Is this possible? I've tried everything to get `Awk` to pick up the `2*NR-1` but nothing seems to work,... What am I doing wrong?

Terry

Comment: Someone can correct me if I'm wrong, but I've never managed using a variable within an interval expression. Also, to use interval expressions, you must set `awk`'s `-r` flag. See the [man](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) page.

Comment: Actually my 1st awk statement does work,... not sure why it works without the -r flag,... At any rate thanks for replying! :)

Answer (score 2):

The method you're trying looks fairly cumbersome. Have you considered using `awk` like this?

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=15; i++) printf (NR == i) ? "1," : "0,"; printf "\n" }' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also go with a combination of coreutils, sed and bash:

```
s=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
seq 16 | while read; do sed 's/0/1/'$REPLY <<< $s; done
```

Comment: Thanks! Only problem is that I have strings with 1000's of 0's so I'd have to replace the 1st line with more code :)

Comment: As long as it doesn't become billions, this should do: `s=$(seq 10000 | sed 's/.*/0,/' | tr -d '\n')`.